# Add timer after click jQuery

Tags: timer, accordion

i have a simple accordion with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.question').click(function() {
        $('div.answer').slideUp(600);   
        $(this).next().slideDown(600);
    });
    $("div.answer").hide();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="question">Question</div>
<div class="answer">Answer</div>
```

How i can add and show a timer before showing answer div?

my request is, after click on Question div, i need to show a 30 sec timer with loading image and after 30 sec i want to show answer div.

thanks :">

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout(f, 30000);` to call function `f` in 30 seconds.

Comment: thanks but i'm not professional! i don't know how i can use your code or show loading image with 30 sec countdown!

Comment: Google "jquery countdown timer" and use one of them instead of trying to do it yourself.